# How to set stripe public key in env file

Tags: laravel

Here is my client side key

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_IS796OfBm2ZFLfvBbwsXHJLK00fE6oqivk');
```

how to set key in env file and how to used key in js file.

Answer (score 2):

**Just do this**

Set in `.env` file

```
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_IS796OfBm2ZFLfvBbwsXHJLK00fE6oqivk
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_*****
```

Get the `key` from `.env` file for whenever to use in controller!

```
\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In .env you write your key as:

```
STRIPE_CLIENT_ID = pk_test_IS796OfBm2ZFLfvBbwsXHJLK00fE6oqivk
```

And in `JS` file:

```
const stripe_id =  "{{ env('STRIPE_CLIENT_ID') }}"
```